# How to Ignore CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, yii

I have UNIQUE INDEX  in mysql table.

So every time I run an insert query and there is a duplicate, I get 500 error
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Publish-Eco-33421-1' for key 'action_type'.

I need this error to be Ignored, when I execute the command.

```
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $command->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround your code with try-catch:

```
try {
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $command->execute();
}
catch(CDbException $e) {
       echo "Got exception:" . $e->getMessage();
}
```